# Redmine 3.0 on Debian "No such file or directory - config/environment.rb"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, redmine

I've install the last version of Redmine on Debian 7. All the install runs very well, from begin to the end. But when I want to access to my Redmine website, I've the following issue :

```
Error message:
No such file or directory - config/environment.rb
```

I've the following installed (with running -v option) :

ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux] 
Rails 4.2.0 
MySQL Server version: 5.5.41-0+wheezy1 (Debian)

Here is my apache2 configuration (sites-available/defaut) :

```
<Directory /var/www/redmine>
    AllowOverride all
    Options -MultiViews
    RailsBaseURI /redmine 
    PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
</Directory>
```

And passenger.conf (mods-available/passenger.conf)

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
    PassengerRoot /usr
    PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
    PassengerDefaultUser www-data
</IfModule>
```

This is the fourth time I try to install Redmine... for the first time all install was run well and again it's not working... I know there is a Debian Package but it still an VERY old version...

I verify that the file environment.rb exist.

If someone can help me please, because I'm getting desperate ^^ I do not know what to do.

I can give more information if you want.

**OR** if someone know a distro with a redmine recent update ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing`<Directory /var/www/redmine>` to `<Directory /var/www/redmine/public>` in your apache config. See http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_Debian_with_Ruby-on-Rails_and_Apache2-Passenger for more details about the config.

Comment: Thanks for try to help me. I've already tried this solution but that change nothing. It says the same thing... I've to say that I have all my redmine folder inside the `/var/www`. Is it poses problem ?